# Error: Operator '[]' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null. }

Tags: dart

```
main() {
    String? variable1=stdin.readLineSync();
    String? variable2=variable1[0]; // Error: Operator '[]' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
}
```

Why do I need to add null check when `variable2` is already `null` safe?
I know how to correct this, please explain why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variable1` is nullable. I believe this has to do with the fact that `readLineSync` returns null if no input is passed. Anyway...

If `variable1` is nullable, this means it *could* be `null`. Reading `null[0]` throws an error, this is why `variable2` needs a null check.

You say you already know how to fix this, I will add the solution here anyway in case anyone else sees this answer and needs a solution.

```
String? variable1=stdin.readLineSync();
String? variable2=variable1?[0];
String variable3='';
if (variable1 != null) {
  variable3 = variable1![0];
}
String variable4 = variable1?[0] ?? 'default';
```

Above, `variable2` will be `null` if and only if `variable1` is null, `variable3` will never be null,  but if `variable1` is `null`, it will be  `''`, likewise, `variable4` will be `'default'` if `variable1` is `null`